# Function in quantmod to get the Volume data column into a Quartile Rank

Tags: r, function, quantmod, quantile

With the help of community I've created the code to download multiple tickers from a .csv file list.

My next step would be to create a column with the quartile rank for the Volume data. What is wrong in my approach?

Here is my approach:

## Load my tickers list from a .csv file, create a list with all of them.

```
library(quantmod)
Tickers <- read.csv("nasdaq_tickers_list.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
getSymbols(Tickers$Tickers,from="2018-08-01", src="yahoo" )
stock_data = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.xts)
all_stocks <- do.call(list, mget(names(stock_data)[stock_data]))
```

## Function to get the Volume column data into a Quartile Rank? What is wrong?

```
Volume_q_rank <- function(x) {
stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Volqrank")
column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
x$volqrank <-as.integer(cut(quantmod::Vo(x),
quantile(x,probs=0:4/4),include.lowest=TRUE))
}
```

## calculate quartile rank for stock volume column and add them to the data

```
all_stocks <- lapply(all_stocks, Volume_q_rank)
```

What is wrong in my function?

## When I run the function I get the following error:

```
Error in quantile.default(coredata(x), ...) : 
missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting this error. I used 103 NASDAQ tickers. But I did adjust your function as it didn't return the correct results. In my case it only returned the value 4 for every record of each ticker.

Adjustments made to the function: One, I made sure that the quantile function also looks at the volume of the stocks. You have it looking at the whole xts object. Now it returns the volume divided in 4 quantiles. 
Secondly, the function was only returning x$volqrank instead of x. I added the last 2 lines to the function to make sure it returns the full xts object.

Here is the new function:

```
Volume_q_rank <- function(x) {
  stock_name <- stringi::stri_extract(names(x)[1], regex = "^[A-Z]+")
  stock_name <- paste0(stock_name, ".Volqrank")
  column_names <- c(names(x), stock_name)
  x$volqrank <- as.integer(cut(quantmod::Vo(x),
                              quantile(quantmod::Vo(x),probs=0:4/4),include.lowest=TRUE))
  x <- setNames(x, column_names)
  return(x)
}

all_stocks <- lapply(all_stocks, Volume_q_rank)

head(all_stocks$MSFT)
           MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted MSFT.Volqrank
2018-08-01    106.03    106.45   105.42     106.28    23628700      105.8726             4
2018-08-02    105.40    108.09   104.84     107.57    26104300      107.1576             4
2018-08-03    107.80    108.05   106.82     108.04    18659600      107.6258             2
2018-08-06    108.12    108.42   107.56     108.13    20265900      107.7155             2
2018-08-07    108.56    109.10   108.17     108.88    16080200      108.4626             1
2018-08-08    109.33    109.75   108.76     109.49    15487500      109.0703             1
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly , as usual ;-), can I ask you what is exactly doing this? (quantmod::Vo(x), quantile(quantmod::Vo(x)), what if I want to use the same Qrank function in other columns (not created by default by quantmod)?  Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Basicly check `?cut`. cut needs the column you want to split, in this case volume, and you need the breaks of the cut, in this case the quantiles will serve as the break points, each 25% falls in one category. In this case the quantiles are defined by the probs (but this is the same as the default). You can use whatever column you want. x[["my_column"]] is the safest way to select it. And use the same column in the quantiles function, or specify your own breaks to use in the cut function.

Comment: Thanks. Will start testing lot of data soon. I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: I have to review the help on how to properly select columns as well. How if the columns are named "MSFT.Positivegap". what is the best way to select all columns for the function? I've tried x[[".Positivegap"]], and lot of other combinations but no success. any help or documentation to check? Thanks again.

Comment: `x[[grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x)]]` should do the trick. Read [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), chapter on subsetting. Search SO for column names and grep. or subsetting and partial strings.

Comment: I have homework for next days... Would you be so kind to have a look at my Edit in your last response? I posted the whole function with new columns subsetting, but I'm having errors...

Comment: what are the column names just before you kick of this function? Could you supply me with an example of the column names of one the tickers? `names(all_stocks$MSFT)`. That should give me an idea of which column name might be an issue.

Comment: The column name for MSFT would be "MSFT.Positivegap", then I would like the function to create the column "MSFT.Positivegapqrank" with Q Rank and apply to all stocks in the list.

Comment: I changed your new function slightly (and fixed a mistake on my part). you need this: `x$posqrank <- as.integer(cut(x[, grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x))],
                               quantile(x[, grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x))],probs=0:4/4),include.lowest=TRUE))` inside your new function.

Comment: Still investigating and testing with functions... What if instead of Quartile rank I'd like to calculate an specific Q number of a column? for example column MSFT.Positivegap calculate what is the Q2.  and use the function to calculate it for all_stocks? So I guess i have to introduce the 0.25 factor next to quantile, but getting errors...     x$q2posgap <- as.integer(cut(x[, grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x))], quantile(x[, grep(".Positivegap", colnames(x))],0.25))